# How many rupees can I earn for Deer Hunting?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Hateno Village near Retsam Forest, Link can play a [Deer Hunting](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Deer_Hunting) mini-game by talking to the farmer Dantz.

Link is rewarded with different amounts of rupees depending on how many deer he can kill in one minute. For example, the reward for killing 9 deer was 20 rupees, while the reward for 10 deer was 50 rupees.

What are the different reward tiers for the deer hunting mini game? What is the largest amount of rupees I can earn?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The highest reward tier for the Deer Hunting game is 50 Rupees.**

During the Deer Hunting Mini-game only 10 Deer spawn, so the maximum reward is 50 Rupees for killing all 10 deer.

Through trawling the internet for videos it appears like the rewards are:

- No Kills: No Reward
- 1-3 Kills: 1 Rupee
- 4-6 Kills: 5 Rupees
- 7-9 Kills: 20 Rupees
- 10 Kills: 50 Rupees

[Example of Perfect game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4FU6E-PM6g).
[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/zelda/comments/6rr3cs/botw_minigame_rewards/).

**Note:** One thing to keep in mind with this game is that the real money is in collecting the Deer/Boar meat. Every time you play the game it will re-spawn the animals so that you can easily farm the Raw Prime Meat. Cooking up 5 of those in a pot and then selling the resulting meal will greatly dwarf any rewards you will get for just killing all 10.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I don't mind either way, swapped it for ya.

Comment: Is it possible to earn more than 10 kills?

Comment: Nope, only 10 Deer Spawn. It also appears like they spawn in set locations, so if you have the Stealth set you can kill them at their spawns without spooking them and having them run all over the place. Have a look at the linked video to see their spawn locations.