# How many rupees can I earn for paragliding from Ridgeland Tower?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

On top of the [*Ridgeland Tower*](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Ridgeland_Tower) in Hyrule Ridge, there is a scientist [Branli](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Branli) studying the Rito bird species.

If you pay him 20 rupees, you can play a paragliding mini game. Brandi will pay link different amounts of rupees depending on how far you glide from the tower.

What are the different reward tiers for the paragliding mini game? How many rupees can I earn?

Comment: [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/zelda/comments/6rr3cs/botw_minigame_rewards/) Reddit post was linked in your [other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/322309/124566) question

Comment: @Wondercricket I hadn’t actually noticed that link. Should I delete this question?

Comment: It’s still a valid question, since it’s a different mini game, but I wasn’t sure if you saw the link or not :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/zelda/comments/6rr3cs/botw_minigame_rewards/) linked to by Wondercricket, if you travel:

- **0m - 499m**: No reward
- **500m - 600m**: A purple (50) rupee
- **600m or more**: A silver (100) rupee.

Additionally, the entrance fee for playing is 20 rupees.